# tkinger - How do I get the correct widget to update in a dynamically created grid?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a grid of Frames from a list of lists. I have a Frame class that has a popup menu bound to Button-1. I'd like to use this pop-up menu to update the label inside the Frame that called the popup menu. Right now only the last Frame's label text is getting updated.

I've tried playing around with bind tags, as I thought maybe the Button-1 is getting bound to only the most recently created widget, but it seems like this was a red herring. I'm actually totally stumped on where to go from here.

```
#!/bin/env python

import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox


def create_grid():
    grid = []
    for i in range(0, 3001, 1000):
        row = []
        for j in range(8):
            row.append(i+j)
        grid.append(row)
    grid.reverse()
    return grid


class GridFrame(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, index, *args, **kwargs):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, root, *args, **kwargs)
        self.labeltext = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.labeltext.set("+")

        self.popup_menu = tkinter.Menu(root, tearoff=0)
        self.popup_menu.add_command(label="Set label to 'test'", command=self.update_label)
        self.popup_menu.add_command(label="Do nothing", command=print)

        self.bind_all("<Button-1>", self.popup)
        self.bind_all("<Button-3>", self.reset_label)

        self.index_label = tkinter.Label(self, text="{0:04d}".format(index))
        self.index_label.pack()
        self.framelabel = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labeltext)
        self.framelabel.pack()

    def popup(self, event):
        try:
            self.popup_menu.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root, 0)
        finally:
            self.popup_menu.grab_release()

    def reset_label(self, event):
        self.labeltext.set("+")

    def update_label(self):
        self.labeltext.set("test")


class GridGUI:
    def __init__(self, root, grid, *args, **kwargs):
        self.root = root
        root.title("Grid")

        for i, row in enumerate(grid):
            for j, index in enumerate(row):
                gridframe = GridFrame(root, index)
                gridframe.config(borderwidth=3, relief="raised")

                gridframe.grid(row=i, column=j, padx=2, pady=2, ipadx=20, ipady=30, sticky="nsew")


def main():
    grid = create_grid()
    root = tkinter.Tk()

    menubar = tkinter.Menu(root)
    filemenu = tkinter.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)

    filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)

    menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

    root.config(menu=menubar)

    my_gui = GridGUI(root, grid)
    root.mainloop()


main()
```

I expect the label in the Frame the popup menu originates would update. With my current code it seems only the label in the most recently created Frame updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using `bind_all`, and that you're resetting that binding every time you create a new `GridFrame`. Thus, only the binding to the last `GridFrame` will be the one recognized by tkinter. When tkinter detects the binding, it calls the `popup` method of the final `GridFrame`.

You can work around this since the event object tells you which widget was clicked on. From that, you can determine which `GridFrame` instance was clicked on. However, there is a simpler solution.

The solution is to *not* use `bind_all`, and instead bind to each widget individually. When the binding fires, it will then call the function associated with the appropriate object.

After creating the widgets, apply a binding to every widget:

```
class GridFrame(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, index, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        for widget in (self, self.index_label, self.framelabel):
            widget.bind("<Button-1>", self.popup)
```

This has the added benefit that you can have any other widgets on the screen that accept button clicks (buttons, scrollbars, etc) without having them be affected by the global binding to a mouse click.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind ugly hacks, here's one way to do it. Instead of creating an individual popup menu within each frame, create only one in your main GUI, check for the popup location, and alter the corresponding `StringVar`.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox

y = []

def create_grid():
    grid_list = []
    for i in range(0, 3001, 1000):
        row = []
        for j in range(8):
            row.append(i+j)
        grid_list.append(row)
    grid_list.reverse()
    return grid_list

class GridFrame(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, index, num, *args, **kwargs):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, root, *args, **kwargs,name=f"{num}")
        self.labeltext = tkinter.StringVar()
        y.append(self.labeltext)
        self.labeltext.set("+")
        self.index_label = tkinter.Label(self, text="{0:04d}".format(index))
        self.index_label.pack()
        self.framelabel = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labeltext)
        self.framelabel.pack()

class GridGUI:
    def __init__(self, root, grid_list, *args, **kwargs):
        root.title("Grid")
        num = 0
        for i, row in enumerate(grid_list):
            for j, index in enumerate(row):
                gridframe = GridFrame(root, index, num)
                gridframe.config(borderwidth=3, relief="raised")
                gridframe.grid(row=i, column=j, padx=2, pady=2, ipadx=20, ipady=30, sticky="nsew")
                num+=1
        self.popup_menu = tkinter.Menu(root, tearoff=0)
        self.popup_menu.add_command(label="Set label to 'test'", command=lambda: self.update_label(self.event))
        self.popup_menu.add_command(label="Do nothing", command=lambda: self.reset_label(self.event))

        root.bind_all("<Button-1>", self.popup)
        root.bind_all("<Button-3>", self.reset_label)

    def popup(self, event):
        self.event = event
        try:
            self.popup_menu.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root, 0)
        finally:
            self.popup_menu.grab_release()

    def reset_label(self, event):
        result = str(event.widget).split(".")[1]
        y[int(result)].set("+")

    def update_label(self,event):
        result = str(event.widget).split(".")[1]
        y[int(result)].set("test")

def main():
    grid = create_grid()
    root = tkinter.Tk()

    menubar = tkinter.Menu(root)
    filemenu = tkinter.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)

    filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)

    menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

    root.config(menu=menubar)

    my_gui = GridGUI(root, grid)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: This is not the ugliest hack I've ever seen, and is definitely usable for my case. I wish tkinter was a little more robust to not require so much global variable usage, but thank you!